# Find a solution using a Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The diophantine equation is 3a + 12b = 132

From the textbook, I set out to find the gcd(3,12) which is 3. 
then I proceed to set up the equation 3s+12t = 0 for any integer s and t

0 = 12(1) + 3(-4)

0 = 12(132) + 3(-4*132)

0 = 12(132 +3m) + 3(-528 -12m)

solve for m

132 +3m =< 0

3m =< -132

m =< -44

but now I have no clue how to proceed from here.

Thanks in advance for your help

Note: I am trying to find the positive solutions

Comment: Solve the homogeneous equation $a+4b=0$ and find a special solution of $a+4b=44$.

Comment: I don't think a gcd can ever be $0$.

Comment: Are you trying to find all solutions in the integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greatest common divisor of the coefficients of the Diophantine equation $3a + 12b = 132$ is $\gcd(3, 12, 132) = 3$.  Divide by $3$ to obtain

$$a + 4b = 44$$

A particular solution in the positive integers is $(1, 10)$.  If $b$ decreases by $1$, then $a$ must increase by $4$.  Hence, the solutions in the positive integers are of the form

\begin{align*}
a & = 4t\\
b & = 11 - t
\end{align*}

where $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, $1 \leq t \leq 10$.  Consequently, the possible solutions in the positive integers are

$$(4, 10), (8, 9), (12, 8), (16, 7), (20, 6), (24, 5), (28, 4), (32, 3), (36, 2), (40, 1)$$